# ¿Cómo puedo autoincrementar número en un input haciendo clic en un boton?

Tags: javascript, html

Me hace falta que un input tenga de primera instancia el valor 1 y que cuando presione un botón se incremente ese valor dentro del input. Este es mi código en html:

```html
<div>
  <label>No. Pregunta</label>
  <input value="" required type="text" id="no_pregunta" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se podría hacer así con `jQuery`:

**UPDATE:**

He editado el código para evitar que retorne `NaN` si el input está vacío.

```js
$("#incrementar").on('click', function() {
    let $input = parseInt($('#no_pregunta').val());
  
    if (isNaN($input)) {
        $('#no_pregunta').val("1")
    } else {
        $('#no_pregunta').val($input + 1);
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "pregunta">
  <label>No. Pregunta</label>
  <input value=" " required type="text" id="no_pregunta" disabled>
  <button id = "incrementar">Incrementar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos por la ayuda, me ha funcionado casi del todo, porque tengo un problema con mi input que no me funciona bien, value="1" no lo toma y entonces cuando presiono el botón para incrementar ese valor me sale dentro del input NaN, no pasa así cuando manualmente escribo el valor 1. Estoy usando la clase .form-control de bootstrap y lo estoy haciendo sobre el template de step-form-wizard, no se si algo de esto tiene que ver. bueno, realmente no se a que se debe el problema.

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado

Comment: Gracias Victor, solo me queda que cuando cargue el wizard donde lo estoy pintando, que ponga el valor 1 como valor inicial, ya eso va por mi. Gacias de nuevo :D

Comment: En el `input` puedes poner el valor inicial que quieras, por ejemplo `value = "1"`

Answer (score 3):

Fíjate en el ejemplo. He añadido un botón con un evento click que lo que hace es obtener el valor de 'no_pregunta' e incrementar 1 cada vez con '++'.

```js
function increment() {
    document.getElementById('no_pregunta').value++;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>No. Pregunta</label>
  <input value="1" required type="text" id="no_pregunta" disabled>
</div>

<button onclick='javascript:increment();'>Incrementa</button>
```